# Tracing iPhone Simulator to speed up launching time

Tags: ios, macos, dtruss

iPhone Simulator takes several minutes to boot-up so I am tracing the elapses time of the system calls to aim speed up the booting time:

```
sudo dtruss -a -f "sudo -u flopez \"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator\"" 3>&1 1>trace.txt 2>trace.txt
```

And I found two specially slow system calls:

```
awk '{ if ($2 >= 50000000 ) print  }' trace.txt 
    PID/THRD   ELAPSD SYSCALL(args)          = return
 1614/0x4dfd:  156374511 select(0x4, 0x7FFCE8404C90, 0x7FFCE84071E0, 0x0, 0x0)       = -1 Err#4
 1645/0x4fbf:  104751284 kevent64(0x3, 0x0, 0x0)         = -1 Err#4
```

Note that the `select()` system call took 104 seg and finally fails, so it would be helpful to discover the file path associated with this call.

How can I find this file?